# Mavros publishes messages as bursts

Tags: ros, mavlink, pixhawk, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a pixhawk connected to an onboard computer over serial port (baud rate 57600). I get /mavros/local_position/odom at ~8 Hz. However, when I plot timestamps of the messages, I get a graph like this : [image: /mavros/local_position/odom/x over timestamp]

What I can see from here is that the odom messages come as bursts.

I'm looking for :

1. What causes this?
2. How can I get a smoother odom output?
3. What additional information would be needed to isolate the problem?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255471/mavros-publishes-messages-as-bursts/) by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 849 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-24**:
I have no experience whatsoever with `mavros`, but you could see whether is uses a buffer of some kind somewhere. Perhaps also check whether it's using TCP (instead of UDP) and Nagle is not turned off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bandwith issue. I had set stream rate to 30 Hz all messages. When I changed it to stream only position data, I got a smoother curve.

`rosservice call /mavros/set_stream_rate 6 30 0`

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2017-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0